# How to pass form data in the url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, serverless

I m working on a project which looks like below image.
[image]
In that for example if i m accessing "The Board" view, I will be filling some data into form and submit to get the actual response.
[image]
Now I want to share the form values which i have filled here as a URL, so that anyone by just clicking on that will have the same response which i m looking at my screen. So that I can use that URL as saved filters hyper link which can be shared publicly to make my life easier while presenting or demonstrating something in meeting.

Not sure if i have described my problem correctly or not, but in simple words I need to form URL which can be used to set the form data and load the response. Because now if I see before and after setting the form data I dont see any difference in the URL, both the times it shows "localhot:3000/board".

My development environment is reactJS for frontend, NodeJS for server and DynamoDB in the backend with AWS Serverless

Let me know if I need to provide any more information

Comment: Are you asking how to add/use a query string to your URL to set/initialize some form fields on the page?

Comment: Yes I think, upon clicking the URL user should be able to directed to the web page with form values set to those values which we have shared via hyperlink.

Comment: As @DrewReese mentioned, all you need is a query string matching criteria from filter (presented on screenshots). So for the example you attached probably something like that: `localhost:3000/board?created_by=123456` is what you'r looking for
where 123456 is the uid for Carlos Fuentes (I'd not send names in query strings, not GDPR compliant

The question is when such a link should be created. Usually, if you have a form, then you have a button (ex: "search"/"apply") and after pressing that button your URL with query string should be created (but not magically but by your implementation)

Comment: Use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) for parsing the query string from the current URL and initialize your form.